# Finding Probability using Moment-Generating Function

Tags: probability-distributions

I am given a moment-generation function $M_x(t)= e^{t+t^2}$ and asked to find the probability that the random variable is greater than $2.5$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look up the moment generating function of the general normal (it was probably done in class and/or book. See what this means about $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in your example.

Answer (score 3):

This is the mgf of a normal distribution. Note that $$M_{X}(t) = \exp \left(\mu t + \frac{\sigma^{2}t^{2}}{2} \right)$$

So $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma^{2} = 2$.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!!